# Xamarin app deployment

Tags: xamarin.ios, xmla

I am wondering how I can actually download the app I created from Xamarin onto my phone (iOS). I am not sure if I have to publish it on the app store or if there is a medium that I take it through so I can use the App?

I am new to coding and made a basic calculator and just want to run it on my phone to test it. Also, I have already tested it through the emulator to know it is working.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/

Comment: Thank you for that Jason, that actually was quite helpful. Is there no way that I can just use it on my phone like a direct download instead of going through the App store.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/